# Objective-c method with unknown number of parameters

Tags: objective-c

I am writing a category against NSMutableString that uses `appendFormat:` internally.

```
@interface NSMutableString (Additions)    
- (void)appendFormatWithLine:(NSString *)format, ...;    
@end

@implementation NSMutableString (Additions)

- (void)appendFormatWithLine:(NSString *)format, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    // **calling [self appendFormat] gives a 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'**
    [self appendFormat:format, args];
    [self appendString:@"\r\n"];

    va_end(args);
}

@end
```

I have no idea how to use va_list or va_start to call `NSMutableString:appendFormat`.  How can this be done?

Comment: This answers to this question might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137752/objective-c-va-list-and-selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well yeah. `-appendFormat:` takes variadic arguments, not a variadic argument list (`va_list`.) There's no single method on `NSMutableString` that takes an argument list, so you should do this instead:

```
NSString *formatted = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format arguments: args];
if (formatted) {
    [self appendString: formatted];
    [formatted release];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this. appendFormat: accepts variadic arguments (the arguments themselves), NOT a va_list structure. In C, it's impossible to pass down variadic arguments.

Your method, however, can be rewritten like this:

```
- (void)appendFormatWithLine:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    // **calling [self appendFormat] gives a 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'**
    NSString *formatString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    [self sppendString:formatString];
    [formatString release];
    [self appendString:@"\r\n"];

    va_end(args);
}
```